# How to find a value in an array of objects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to:

1. Find the cheapest and most expensive food and drink.
2. Find the **id** and **name** of drinks and foods if their price is higher than 10.

My attempt:

```
 let menu = [
            { id: 1,  name: "Soda",price: 3.12,size: "4oz",type: "Drink" },
            { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" }
            ]
```

I would be happy and thankful if anybody could help.
Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example :

```
let menu = [
            { id: 1,  name: "Soda",price: 3.12,size: "4oz",type: "Drink" },
            { id: 2, name: "Beer", price: 6.50, size: "8oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 3, name: "Margarita", price: 12.99, size: "12oz", type: "Drink" },
            { id: 4, name: "Pizza", price: 25.10, size: "60oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 5, name: "Kebab", price: 31.48, size: "42oz", type: "Food" },
            { id: 6, name: "Berger", price: 23.83, size: "99oz", type: "Food" }
        ];
        
function getCheapest(array) {
    return Math.min(...array.map(item => item.price));
}

function getExpensive(array) {
    return Math.max(...array.map(item => item.price));
}

function getFoodsAndDrinksMoreThan(array, minVal = 10){
        return array.filter(item => item.price > minVal).map(item => ({id: item.id, name: item.name}));
}

console.log(getCheapest(menu));

console.log(getExpensive(menu));

console.log(getFoodsAndDrinksMoreThan(menu));
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one could be achieved with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) by comparing the first and second argument of the function you pass into it and returning the smaller one.

For 2. that sounds like a case for [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to me.

Let me know if you need more guidance.